# Fullcalendar refetch events callback

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, fullcalendar, jquery-callback

Currently using fullcalendar.io

In the documentation, it has calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents') that refetch all the events from the server.

In short, I want calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents') request to be completed and send me back a callback to let me know. I want all the events to be downloaded before i proceed with certain tasks.

How can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried to listen eventAfterAllRender http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/?

Comment: @kostya is there an example how to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it by doing refetch events after a successful http post as below

```
  Service.insert(event).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert('error');
            });
```

Comment: calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents'); where is this `calendar` instance come from ? I use ` <FullCalendar id="cal" :options="calendarOptions" />` to render my calendar(vueJs)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({


                defaultView: 'month',
                editable: true,
                //eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

                events: myevents,


            });
```

Comment: Works, but I wish not to remove the calendar and later reload it again with the filtered evens. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed basic-views.html from demos folder of FullCalendar. I added

```
        ,
        eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
            console.log('eventAfterAllRender');
            console.log(view);
        }
```

To calendar options list. It fires after initial events load and after each $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );

Full demo code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='../fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='../fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2014-11-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2014-11-01'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: '2014-11-07',
                    end: '2014-11-10'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2014-11-09T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2014-11-16T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Conference',
                    start: '2014-11-11',
                    end: '2014-11-13'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2014-11-12T10:30:00',
                    end: '2014-11-12T12:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: '2014-11-12T12:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2014-11-12T14:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Happy Hour',
                    start: '2014-11-12T17:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Dinner',
                    start: '2014-11-12T20:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2014-11-13T07:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2014-11-28'
                }
            ],
            eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
                console.log('eventAfterAllRender');
                console.log(view);
            }
        });
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
    });

</script>
<style>

    body {
        margin: 40px 10px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is partly doing what i wanted. This method is being called everytime. I only want it to be called after $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' ); Wondering whether there is a better way

Comment: Also, the method is being called for $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'updateEvent' );

Comment: This IS the correct answer. This works even if the data set is empty and nothing gets rendered (as opposed to eventAfterRender, which triggers on each item).
You could use boolean checks in the function you call (and set these if you want to change something)